# NameError trying to use get_output_names from mido

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, nameerror

I'm trying to get to grips with a Python module I've installed called 'mido' for handling MIDI I/O.

The function [`mido.get_output_names`](https://mido.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ports.html) should tell me what output ports are available, but, when I try to use it in the interactive interpreter, I get the following error(s):

```
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 07:18:10) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from mido import *
>>> mido.get_output_names()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'mido' is not defined
>>> get_output_names()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'get_output_names' is not defined
>>>
```

I've seen other questions with similar issues, but the suggested solution seems to be to name the package before the call (in this case 'mido.') but as you can see that doesn't seem to make a difference here.

I've also tried putting the code in a .py file and interpreting/running that and I get the same error messages (for with and without the '.mido' respectively)

Can anyone help me work out what I've missed?

I've also tried `from mido.port import *` and calls to `port.get_output_names()` in as many combinations as I could think of, with similar equivalent `NameError` messages.

Comment: try `import mido` and after that you can see available methods with `dir(mido)` maybe this brings you a step further

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [`__init__.py` file of the `mido` module](https://github.com/olemb/mido/blob/stable/mido/__init__.py#L111) you can see that it prevents star `*` imports by setting `__all__` to an empty list:

```
# Prevent splat import.
__all__ = []
```

<sup>`__all__` is the list of names picked up by `from mod import *`, setting it to `[]` makes sure nothing gets imported.</sup>

it also sets a couple of additional functions (like `get_output_names`) in the module dictionary via use of the [`set_backend` helper function](https://github.com/olemb/mido/blob/stable/mido/__init__.py#L114).

So, either import `mido` directly and use `get_output_names` by prefixing the module name:

```
import mido
mido.get_output_names(...)
```

or, import the name from the module and use it directly:

```
from mido import get_output_names
get_output_names(...)
```

Comment: Never occurred to me that was a thing which could be done :o Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

seems strange, maybe try this way:

```
import mido
```

then when calling functions from the package, use:

```
mido.get_output_names()
```

you can also import this way:

```
import mido as md
```

then:

```
md.get_output_names()
```

Also:
- try to get to the package directory, and have a look in the files
- try to get help from the package from terminal when imported:

```
import mido
help(mido)
```